# Force Closing for notes.java (sharedpreferences)

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Do i have to declare something in android manifest? I'm trying to have text input that is in notes.java save even when the activity is destroyed. So i used SharedPreferences. "editText1" is the text input in notes.xml When i run the app it force closes Here's notes.java:

```
public class notes extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    private EditText mEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);


       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       String savedText = settings.getString("text", "");
       mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       mEditText.setText(savedText);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putString("text", mEditText.getText().toString());

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Here's the Logcat for when it force closes:

> 03-17 16:54:42.302: E/AndroidRuntime(14558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-17 16:54:42.302: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{izzy.n/izzy.n.notes}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-17 16:54:42.302: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>   03-17 16:54:42.302: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
>   03-17 16:54:42.302: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132) 03-17
>   16:54:42.302: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
>   03-17 16:54:42.302: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-17
>   16:54:42.302: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView` before `findViewById`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```